# Why wont my website show up?

Tags: html, css

I have create my website and have a domain but when I type the domain name into the browser I get some weird page. I am using 000webhosting and just uploaded the files and they said they were good. I am not sure what is the problem but here is the link

hudsonreamer.com

Hopefully I can get some help
Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Your question does not relate to programming. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have completely changed the question by your edit, which I will revert. If you want to ask a new question, please ask a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and not by completely revamping this one

Comment: How do I get rid of this one

Comment: May you get rid of it

Comment: @TerryA mAy you get rid of it please I realize it was a bad question

Comment: @CookieM You are free to delete the question yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your DNS/Nameserver records to link files to domain.
Not really covered here however you may want to watch a youtube tutorial on setting up a hosted website.